# backing up big database on shared hosting. tried mysqldump and phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, mysql

So i am on godaddy shared hosting. need to backup db and data of some 20 tables with 500mb data.

**solution tried :**

**1. solution : phpmyadmin**

tried simply exporting the table and it starts exporting but fails in between because of error

```
mysql server has gone away
```

So tried to solve this problem by increasing wait_timeout but failed in it as well because i am on shared hosting it does not permit me. gives me error something like this

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

**2. Solution tried : mysqldump**

Ran following command to backup a table with 110000 rows

```
mysqldump --user xxxxx --password=XXXXXXXXX Username wp_pc_products >> wp_pc_product.sql
```

This resulted in a file size of 55M And contains only 124 rows.

```
55M wp_pc_product.sql
```

Actual problem :

Trying to migrate my database from shared hosting to VPS.

Comment: check the tail end of that .sql file. if it doesn't end cleanly (e.g. stops in the middle of a query line), then the dump is suffering from the same timeout/abort condition your #1 solution is, and you'll have to talk to godaddy for help.

Comment: No i already checked .. It does not contain any error. last line of file `-- Dump completed on 2016-07-14 11:38:17
`

Comment: then that dump should beok. how'd you figure out the 500meg sizing? line counts don't necessarily have to match rowcounts in the db, especially if you enabled the extended insert syntax. then you get only one insert with multiple values fields, isntead of a 500 `insert ... values ..`, you get `isnert .. values (set1), (set2), (set3), etc...` on a single line.

Comment: I know the number of rows in my table. The whole db is 500mb this table which i dumped is only 60Mb with 101998 rows in it. I checked this in phpmyadmin

Comment: Before we go any further - have you tried backing it up using the godaddy manager? You can then FTP the file to wherever you wish? maybe interesting? https://uk.godaddy.com/help/backing-up-and-restoring-mysql-or-mssql-databases-5648

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` needs only one `>` & not two `>>`. Can you change that?

For the `wp_pc_products` table, can you identify as to which row from the mysql table is the last one to be exported. What happens if you try to export the whole database using `mysqldump` with the `-p` option. Does that work?
Did you try exporting any other table & see if they are being exported fully or not?

Comment: that's not going to matter. `>` outputs to a file and overwrites any existing one. `>>` simply creates/appends. it doesn't change the data.

Comment: I firstly tried using one > not two.. the reults were same for single >operator

Comment: how can i find that which row from the table is exported last. do i need to check it manually. i dont know which sorting it might have done.

Comment: Find out the id of the last record which is there in the .sql file. It should follow a sort order which is based on when the records are created.

Comment: tried for different table and in this case only 85 rows in the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Maybe the max allowed size is 55MB, try this command in mysql shell:

```
show variables like 'max%' ;
```

It will display the max allowed size in bytes.

You could try set the max allowed packet size to 600MB with this command:

```
set max_allowed_packet = 600*1024;
```

**Solution 2**

Since you have found a limit to the rows you can dump, then you can perform multiple smaller dumps with this flag:

```
--where="1 limit 100"
```

And you keep incrementing it like:

```
--where="101 limit 200"
```

Documentation about [--max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

Documentation about [--where](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) flag

Answer (score 0):

Try installing HeidiSQL from http://www.heidisql.com/download.php

You can then transfer directly between the databases or to your local machine using the export tab, see http://www.heidisql.com/help.php#sqlexport for details.